# How to speed up this federated query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I have a query which brings people who a `dbo:Writer` and have different birth-dates stated in DBpedia and Wikidata. I wrote it initially to be run independently but currently I'm running on Wikidata. It's quite slow and the interesting thing is that when I don't call with Wikidata endpoint with `SERVICE`, which I can afford to do here, it gets even slower. I'd be interested to learn why it is so. But my main question is, how to optimize it? Here is the query:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?personDBP ?personWD ?personWDLabel ?BirthDateDBP ?BirthDateWD

WHERE {


   SERVICE <http://dbpedia.org/sparql> {
      ?personDBP a dbo:Writer ;
      dbo:birthDate ?BirthDate_DBP;
      owl:sameAs ?personWD .
      FILTER REGEX (?personWD, "wikidata.org")
      BIND (xsd:date(?BirthDate_DBP) AS ?BirthDateDBP)
   }

    SERVICE <https://query.wikidata.org/sparql>  {
      ?personWD wdt:P569 ?BirthDate_WD .
      BIND (xsd:date(?BirthDate_WD) AS ?BirthDateWD)  
    }

FILTER (?BirthDateDBP != ?BirthDateWD)

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }

}

ORDER BY DESC(?BirthDateDBP)

LIMIT 50
```

Comment: it all depends on the federated query engine. I mean, there are obviously multiple ways to compute the result ,the most obvious to just fetch all the data from both services and do the join. clearly, this can be expensive, if the resultset from both SERVICEs is large, i.e. it has to fetch a lot's of data and even more worse, do the join on those afterwards without the ability to make use of optimized data structures of even database indices etc.

Comment: the other way could be to compute just one part of the query and "pipe" the intermediate bindings into the other request, i.e. we bring the load to the other SERVICE then.

Comment: long story short, this is all implementation dependent, the SPARQL standard doesn't restrict the implementation in any direction - it just has to return the correct result in the end - not surprising, I know.

Comment: Regarding your question, you can try Blazegraph query hints:https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/FederatedQuery

Comment: ah, and before I forget - the DBpedia public endpoint has a default limit of 10 000 results per query, thus, your query will be incomplete anyways. You could only workaorund this "pagination" via a subquery inside the SERVICE, but unfortunately not via a single SPARQL query.